# Where to find official detailed explanation about Spark internals

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to learn Spark in detail.
Their are many sites which explain Spark in detail. Like these links:

1. [Spark stages](https://data-flair.training/blogs/spark-stage/)
2. [DAG in spark](https://data-flair.training/blogs/dag-in-apache-spark/)

My doubt is where all these things are explained on [spark official website](https://spark.apache.org) in similar or more details?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't looked at these already, you might want to start with the foundations:

- Original RDD Paper: https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2011/EECS-2011-82.pdf
- Spark SQL / Dataframes: https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/SparkSQLSigmod2015.pdf

**UPDATE:**

Similar and more publications on the topic are available here:

- https://spark.apache.org/research.html
- https://spark.apache.org/history.html

Also, you might find interesting stuff in other formats if you dig deeper into the https://spark.apache.org/documentation.html (e.g. Meetup Talk Video: "Introduction to Spark Internals (slides) by Matei Zaharia, at Yahoo in Sunnyvale, 2012-12-18")

Comment: Still nothing on [official site](https://spark.apache.org/)? Also, just curious, are the writers of these papers spark implementors?

Comment: Well, Berkeley (Matei Zaharia) invented Spark. And Databricks is the #1 contributor and official company behind it.

Comment: Thats good resource. But still thinking there should be detailed docs on official site.

Comment: Updated the answers with specific references from their official website. I agree that they are a bit hard to find. I hope that it's what you are looking for!